# In VS Code, how can I avoid to open more than one file for each editor group?

Tags: visual-studio-code

To be more productive on my work, I'd like to have the possibility to open only one file for each editor group.
My purpose is to avoid to have 20 or more tabs opened at the and of the day and lost time searching for the right opened file in that list.

I'd like to focus the desired editor group (CMD + 1, 2, 3, 4) and open a new file (CMD + p). If a file is opened in the selected editor group, I'd like to have the possibility to save it and replace it with the new one.

I think that to have at most 4 file opened at the same time is perfect and this forces me to be more focused on the code, instead of search for a file in a very big list of opened tabs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not native functionality. If there isn't an extension to do it you could look to write one (others might like to work the same way).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> If you wish to restrict the number of opened tabs, or close tabs automatically depending upon the threshold of an opened tab in the workspace

No more plugin needed: the next VSCode 1.42 (Q1 2020) will have a new setting for [limiting the number of open editors](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/23dfcc98bf6b78a2530afb2efe297fd9b60d77d7/release-notes/v1_42.md#limit-the-number-of-open-editors)

There are new settings to limit the maximum number of editors that are open at the one time.

> - `workbench.editor.limit.enabled`: Enable this feature (off by default).
> - `workbench.editor.limit.perEditorGroup`: Whether to apply the limit per editor group or across all groups.
> - `workbench.editor.limit.value`: The maximum number of open editors (10 by default).
>
> If enabled, VS Code will close the least recently used editor when you open a new editor.
>
> Below you can see the behavior when the limit is set to 3:
>
> [image: https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_42/editor-limit.gif]

---

As noted in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550412/vscode-how-to-avoid-to-open-more-than-one-file-for-each-editor-group/59972166?noredirect=1#comment119940201_59972166) by [Timo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705829/timo): see "[User Interface/ Editor Groups](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_editor-groups)".

---

VSCode 1.67 (Apr. 2022) will propose

```
workbench.editor.limit.excludeDirty
```

> Controls if the maximum number of opened editors should exclude dirty editors for counting towards the configured limit.

See [issue 144309](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144309) and [PR 144545](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/144545).

Comment: Thank you! I have to use VSCode for a client instead of vim. I got very close to my normal workflow by removing tabs and implementing pane switching via shortcuts, but was very frustrated that jumping to a definition or switching files r was in fact opening a new editor buffer on top of the current editor, despite not showing the files because I disabled tabs. 

That behavior broke`ctrl-o` `ctrl-i` navigation, as well as expected behavior from quitting a file because instead of closing the pane it would show the editor below. Limiting the number of open editors to 1 per group solves this.

Comment: [info](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_editor-groups) on editor groups if you are new to VSCode.

Comment: @Timo Thank you. I have included the link you mention in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to restrict the number of opened tabs, or close tabs automatically depending upon the threshold of an opened tab in the workspace.

Zen Tabs plugin might be the solution.

Your requirements :

- The tabs usually close silently without any notification
- The threshold, as you can see from the settings, is usually fixed, but I like the idea of changing it dynamically with the intent to prevent scrolling.

[Zen Tabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hitode909.zentabs) is the extension you are looking for.

[image: restict tabs]

You can get additional info [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_working-without-tabs).

Comment: Perfect, it does exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

You'd put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"workbench.editor.limit.enabled": true,
"workbench.editor.limit.perEditorGroup": true,
"workbench.editor.limit.value": 1,
```

Note that you could technically also do `"workbench.editor.showTabs": "single",` instead, but that doesn't actually limit the number of editors per editor group. It only makes it so that the active editor in the group is displayed in the tab bar.