# Force VSCode to have only 1 file opened

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

I want VSCode to have only a single file tab (editor) at a time. When I switch files VSCode should replace the opened file with a new one instead of creating a new tab (editor) for it.

`"workbench.editor.showTabs": false` makes it so that there is only 1 tab visible. This is exactly how I want things to look like, but under the hood VSCode still creates a new tab for each file. You can see them if you set this parameter back to true or try to cycle through tabs with `Ctrl+Tab`.

Comment: related but not a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52550412/11107541

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are these 3 settings that do exactly what I want to achieve:

```json
// Disable tabs visually
"workbench.editor.showTabs": false,
// Enable the limit for number of opened tabs
"workbench.editor.limit.enabled": true,
// Set max amount of opened tabs. Older tabs will be closed
"workbench.editor.limit.value": 1,
```

There is also an extension called [zentabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hitode909.zentabs) but has some flaws and is pretty much obsolete since what it does can be achieved natively.